# How to remove attributes from the NSAttributedString swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, setattribute, nsmutableattributedstring

I have added some attributes to my buttons attributedTitle

```
 let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: currTitle)

 attr.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attr.length))
 attr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0,  attr.length))

 currButton?.setAttributedTitle(attr, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

How can I remove NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName from it after button click?

Comment: Wow.

That is the question, what I was interested in.

Thank you for the question.

It's miracle. Please share it

Comment: You're welcome PiraTa... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `removeAttribute` method:

```
attr.removeAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, range: NSMakeRange(0, attr.length))
```

Comment: i want to remove the strike data, when i click on a button, but by this code always i am getting unstriked button text

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple. You can use this method from [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/removeAttribute:range:) class

```
func removeAttribute(_ name: String,
               range range: NSRange)
```

In your case

```
attr.removeAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName , range:NSMakeRange(0, attr.length))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "YourStringHere")
attributeString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
yourLblHere.attributedText = attributeString
```